# where should i catch the exception???? main public method? or private method?

Tags: java, try-catch

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.management.MemoryUsage;
import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.management.JMX;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.tuniu.myMonitor.dataCollection.IDataCollection;
import com.tuniu.myMonitor.protocol.Performance.GCInfo;
import com.tuniu.myMonitor.protocol.Performance.PerformanceBean;
import com.tuniu.myMonitor.utils.CommonConstants;
import com.tuniu.myMonitor.utils.CommonUtils;


public class DataCollectionImpl implements IDataCollection{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(DataCollectionImpl.class);

    private static final String SERVICE_URL = new StringBuffer(CommonConstants.RMI_PREFIX)
    .append(CommonConstants.RMI_HOST).append(CommonConstants.RMI_PORT).append(CommonConstants.RMI_SUFFIX)
    .toString();

    public PerformanceBean collectPerformanceInfo() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        MBeanServerConnection mBeanSConnection = null;
        MemoryUsage heapMemoryUsage = null;
        MemoryUsage nonHeapMemoryUsage = null;
        OperatingSystemMXBean osInfo = null;
        Map<String, String> gcInfo = null;
        try {
            mBeanSConnection = CommonUtils.getMBeanSConnector(SERVICE_URL);
            heapMemoryUsage = getMemoryUsage(mBeanSConnection, CommonConstants.HEAPMEMORYUSAGE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
            nonHeapMemoryUsage = getMemoryUsage(mBeanSConnection, CommonConstants.NONHEAPMEMORYUSAGE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
            osInfo = getOSInfo(mBeanSConnection);
            gcInfo = getJstatFields();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (isNotNull(mBeanSConnection, heapMemoryUsage, nonHeapMemoryUsage, osInfo, gcInfo)) {
            // TODO add log
            return null;
        }

        PerformanceBean performBean = null;
        performBean = PerformanceBean
                .newBuilder()
                .setArch(osInfo.getArch())
                .setAvailableProcessors(osInfo.getAvailableProcessors())
                .setOsName(osInfo.getName())
                .setSystemLoadAverage(osInfo.getSystemLoadAverage())
                .setCommittedHeap(heapMemoryUsage.getCommitted())
                .setInitHeap(heapMemoryUsage.getInit())
                .setUsedHeap(heapMemoryUsage.getUsed())
                .setMaxHeap(heapMemoryUsage.getMax())
                .setInitNonHeap(nonHeapMemoryUsage.getInit())
                .setCommittedNonHeap(nonHeapMemoryUsage.getCommitted())
                .setUsedNonHeap(nonHeapMemoryUsage.getUsed())
                .setMaxNonHeap(nonHeapMemoryUsage.getMax())
                .setGc(GCInfo.newBuilder().setJstatS0(Double.valueOf(gcInfo.get(CommonConstants.S0)))
                        .setJstatS1(Double.valueOf(gcInfo.get(CommonConstants.S1)))
                        .setJstatE(Double.valueOf(gcInfo.get(CommonConstants.E)))
                        .setJstatO(Double.valueOf(gcInfo.get(CommonConstants.O)))
                        .setJstatP(Double.valueOf(gcInfo.get(CommonConstants.P)))
                        .setJstatYGC(Double.valueOf(gcInfo.get(CommonConstants.YGC)))
                        .setJstatYGCT(Double.valueOf(gcInfo.get(CommonConstants.YGCT)))
                        .setJstatFGC(Double.valueOf(gcInfo.get(CommonConstants.FGC)))
                        .setJstatFGCT(Double.valueOf(gcInfo.get(CommonConstants.FGCT)))
                        .setJstatGCT(Double.valueOf(gcInfo.get(CommonConstants.GCT)))).build();

        LOGGER.info("cost:{}", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // mapper.writeValue(new
        // File("D:\\Users\\zhangshuo\\Desktop\\perBean.json"), perfBean);
        //
        // mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValue(new
        // File("D:\\Users\\zhangshuo\\Desktop\\perBean.json"), performBean);
        return performBean;

    }
    //TODO refactor with JMX Proxy
    private MemoryUsage getMemoryUsage(MBeanServerConnection mBeanSConnection,String attribute) throws Exception{
        MemoryUsage heapMemoryUsage = null;

            ObjectName  heapObjName = new ObjectName(CommonConstants.MEMORY_OBJECT_NAME);
            heapObjName = new ObjectName(CommonConstants.MEMORY_OBJECT_NAME);
            heapMemoryUsage = MemoryUsage.from((CompositeDataSupport) mBeanSConnection.getAttribute(heapObjName,
                    attribute));
        return heapMemoryUsage;
    }

    private OperatingSystemMXBean getOSInfo(MBeanServerConnection mBeanSConnection) throws Exception{
    ObjectName osObjectName=null;
    OperatingSystemMXBean osMBeanProxy = null;
        osObjectName = new ObjectName(CommonConstants.OPERATIONSYSYTEM_OBJECT_NAME);
        osMBeanProxy = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mBeanSConnection, osObjectName, OperatingSystemMXBean.class);
    return osMBeanProxy;

    }

    private Map<String, String> getJstatFields() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> jstatFields = new HashMap<String, String>();
            jstatFields = getGCInfo();
            // TODO log error
        return jstatFields;
    }

    private  Map<String, String> getGCInfo() throws Exception{
        // linux
        // String[] cmd = new String[] { CommonConstants.BASH_CMD,
        // CommonConstants.C_CMD, CommonConstants.JSTAT_COMAND };
        String cmd = "jstat -gcutil 6764";
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        BufferedReader inBr = null;
        Process p = run.exec(cmd);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream());
        inBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String lineStr = null;
        String[] fieldsName = null;
        String[] fieldsValue = null;
        while ((lineStr = inBr.readLine()) != null) {
            lineStr = lineStr.trim();
            if (lineStr.startsWith("S")) {
                fieldsName = new String(lineStr.getBytes()).replaceAll("\\s+", "|").split("\\|");
            } else {
                fieldsValue = new String(lineStr.getBytes()).replaceAll("\\s+", "|").split("\\|");
            }
        }
        if (p.waitFor() != 0) {
            if (p.exitValue() == 1)
                System.err.println("fail ");
        }
        Map<String, String> fields = null;
        if (fieldsName.length == fieldsValue.length) {

            fields = new HashMap<String, String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < fieldsName.length; i++) {
                fields.put(fieldsName[i], fieldsValue[i]);
            }
        }
        inBr.close();
        in.close();
        return fields;
    }

    private boolean isNotNull(MBeanServerConnection mBeanSConnection,MemoryUsage heapMemoryUsage,MemoryUsage nonHeapMemoryUsage,OperatingSystemMXBean osInfo,Map<String,String> gcInfo){

       return  (null != heapMemoryUsage)&&(null != nonHeapMemoryUsage) && (null != mBeanSConnection) && (null != osInfo) && (null!=gcInfo);

        }
}
```

Every private method I throw exception instead of trying catch immediately. Finally, I catch all exception on the main method.

When should I try catch or  throws? Please  someone help ! 
Am i right?

Comment: That depends on how you want to handle it.

Comment: Two links that will help you to improve your questions: 1- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , 2- http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/ Please summarize better your question, and make it more precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though question seems to be very broad, but you need understanding on Java Exception framework + bit of design patterns

1.) If you are exposing some public methods in a service, it is always better to catch exception

```
Log Exception -> Return proper error code/message
```

2.) throwing exception means everyone who is calling that method has to handle the exception on its own.

3.) If there are any changes to the internal implementation of the method, then you might end up throwing a different exception.

4.) Also throwing the `superclass Exception`, again looses the focus from the precision.